# Error: Trying to get property of non-objet

Tags: laravel-5

Intento crear un array tras una consulta. Me da el error de trying to get property of non-objet

Controlador:

```
public function index()
    {
    $diccionario=MDiccionario::all();
    $categorias=MCategoria::all();

    $diccionario2=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($diccionario as $item){

        $diccionario2[$i]=array(
                                 'id' => $item->id,
                                 'nombre' => $item->nombre,
                                 'categoria' => $item->categoria,
                                 'definicion' => $item->definicion
        ); 
        ++$i;
    }


    return view('web\diccionario')
        ->with('diccionario',$diccionario2)
        ->with('categorias',$categorias);
}
```

Blade

```
           @foreach($diccionario as $item)

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                        <td>{{ $item['nombre'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $item['categoria'] }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $item['definicion'] }}</td>
                                        <td class="center"> 
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{{route('diccionario/destroy',['id' => $item->id] )}}" >Delete</a></td>

                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: ¿puedes poner en qué linea te da el error? De todas formas el problema creo que lo tienes en la forma de acceder a $item para recuperar el id (accedes con el operador '->' ), ya que declaras $item como un array.

Comment: No me dice linea de error. He probado como tú dices. Pero tu respuesta me ha servido para fijarme que en al ruta está mal puesto (['id' => $item->id])

Comment: No me dice linea de error. He probado como tú dices. Pero tu respuesta me ha servido para fijarme que en al ruta está mal puesto (['id' => $item->id])

Comment: Lo único que creo q te puede dar el error en el código es el fragmento: `{{route('diccionario/destroy',['id' => $item->id] )}}` que lo cambiaría por: `{{route('diccionario/destroy',array('id' => $item['id']) )}}`